# Godot took over .scn files in Xcode

Tags: xcode, scenekit, godot

Recently installed Godot. Now Xcode will not preview .scn files. I can't change the type back to SceneKit as it isn't available in the dropdown list.

Comment: I doubt Godot can do much about this. Xcode is coincidently using this same extension. And adding it to the dropdown list you mentioned is what they(Xcode devs) need to do. Maybe raise an issue at https://developer.apple.com/support.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. Open **finder** and locate any file with the *.scn* extension.
2. Click on *Get Info*
3. Navigate to the session **Open with:**
4. Select **Xcode** from the list and click in *change all*

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't work… even if Godot 3.1.1 is removed completely, the Xcode editor will still say it's a "Godot Scene" and you can't change it.

Comment: Are you sure @tjgrant, I tested on multiple devices, worked fine here.

Comment: So a little clarification, for this to work, you have to ensure the Godot app is actually deleted from the system. If it’s in the Trash folder but not actually deleted, Xcode will still not reclaim ownership of the .scn extension. But if you ensure that Godot has been deleted from your system entirely, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also right-click on the .scn file in Xcode's Project navigator and select `Open As` → `SceneKit Document`

Answer (score 0):

Other answers did not work for me. However @tjgrant's comment worked.

I had to uninstall Godot from mac. And remove it from Trash as well. I know this is not ideal solution, but for those who are not working on SceneKit files and Godot simultaneously this is the easiest solution.

I plan to install Godot later when I am done with SceneKit work.