# Cannot see the graph scene in Xcode 11

Tags: xcode, scenekit

I'm using the Xcode 11 with Mojave 10.14.6 and can't see the Graph Scene. I tried clicking on the "No selection" since it was suggested in other places but not is happening.

My laptop is MacBook Air 1.7GHz i7, 8GB ram - which was recently preinstalled and the hard drive was formatted

**Edit: More specs**

Metal:  Supported, feature set macOS GPUFamily1 v4

[here is a screenshot that shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2oJq.png)

Comment: This is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708967/godot-took-over-scn-files-in-xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the icon, it seems that you have Godot installed and it claimed ownership of documents with the `scn` file extension.

You can right-click on the file in Xcode's Project navigator and select `Open As` → `SceneKit Document`.

Comment: I don't have Open As → SceneKit Document also the change of ownership didn't work.. but after deleting Godot it started working! Thanks mate